# Unmatched records missing from spatial left join

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I have a polygons table and a points table.
I want to get for each polygon the number of points located in it and have zero for polygons with no points.
However with the following query I miss the polygons with zero points.
I expected the LEFT JOIN to keep them though.
I guess the st_transform is not causing this issue.

```
select plg.id,plg.geom,count(distinct pnt.id) as num_pnt
from polygons plg
left join points pnt
on st_contains(plg.geom,st_transform(pnt.geom,3003))
where pnt.fieldx = "xx"
group by plg.id,plg.geom;`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try moving the where clause to a join condition:

```
select plg.id,p lg.geom, count(pnt.id) as num_pnt
from polygons plg
left join points pnt
on st_contains(plg.geom,st_transform(pnt.geom,3003)) and pnt.fieldx = 'xx' --Like this
group by plg.id, plg.geom;
```

See [SQL JOIN - WHERE clause vs. ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

If you join first, then filter with a where clause, all rows where there are no match in the right table **and** rows where  `pnt.fieldx <> 'xx'` will be removed from the join result.

Comment: thanks, it worked.
I don't fully understand why though.

Comment: this answers my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Answer (score 3):

The issue come from :

```
where pnt.fieldx = 'xx'
```

If no point are matching, `pnt.fieldx` is `NULL`, so the `WHERE` is not true.
Just replace the where clause:

```
where pnt.fieldx = 'xx' or pnt.fieldx is NULL
```

Or add the condition in the join clause :

```
select plg.id,plg.geom,count(distinct pnt.id) as num_pnt
from polygons plg
left join points pnt on
     st_contains(plg.geom,st_transform(pnt.geom,3003)) 
     and pnt.fieldx = 'xx'
group by plg.id,plg.geom;
```

Comment: thanks, but first option doesn't work and would be correct as a condition in my case.

Comment: would not* be correct